# Error DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. on windows 10 on a macbook (dualboot)

Tags: uwp, windows-10, appxmanifest

I'm trying to work from home on a UWP project, on a macbook with dualboot using windows 10, in visual studio 2015.

(So it's not on a virtual machine, which is what I find everywhere when looking for this problem)

I thought I have everything correctly set up, but when I try to run the project, I get the error:

> Error      DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. Rejecting a request to register from AppxBundleManifest.xml because the manifest is not in the package root. (0x80073cf9) Ambiorix.UWP

Windows is set to developer mode, and I have the windows 10 anniversary update installed.
And the file Package.appxmanifest is in fact in the root of the project. Which I was told is the manifest it is complaining about (or contains it? I don't know much about manifest files)

I have no clue at to what might be causing this, any help much appreciated.

If you need more info, just tell me, I just don't know what else to add.

Comment: Are you developing a uwp app on a Mac with windows 10 installed? How about create a blank project with visual studio and run?

Comment: Package.appxmanifest is not the package manifest file - it is a development file that is an input for the package manifest file. If you open your project in Windows Explorer, and go to bin -> (debug or release), you should see the AppxManifest. Do you see that file there?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, but in a windows 10 machine. This app was working fine and was published in the store. But now I'm getting this error every time I want to run it.

Comment: Apparently, this problem is of no interest to anyone. The error message is misleading as the manifest file in fact exists in the package root. Unfortunately, ProcMon does not help either (I had expected it to show a failed search for that file).

Answer (score 20):

In my case, app was installed by another user. After deleting it, error was gone.

Comment: For anyone else having the same problem, it looks like the "it" you need to "delete" is the other user account, not the app. Uninstalling the app from the other user's account wasn't sufficient; removing the entire other user account solved the issue for me.

Comment: In my case it was the app that I had to delete. I had installed it from the Microsoft Store, but I had to uninstall it first before I could begin developing/deploying it from Visual Studio again.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar error, in deploying a blank UWP project (created with the `Blank App (Universal Windows)`) template.

> DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF0] error
>   0x80070003: Opening file from location: AppxManifest.xml failed with
>   error: The system cannot find the path specified..

After reading the answers here I had hunch that the problem may have been that he project was on a network drive. So, first I created the same project on the local hard drive (under C:\Users...), and it ran OK.

To fix the project on the network drive, I edited the `Project -> Properties -> Debug` and set the `Target device` to `Remote Machine`, the Remote machine to `Localhost` and the `Authentication Mode` to `Windows`.

Comment: Exactly my problem! I had trouble because my path was too long (exceed 260 chars) so I used `subst` to map a drive to my folder. Couldn't deploy it. Changing Target Device helped.

Comment: thanks for this, this saved me from needing to have a separate copy of my git repo on the windows VM

Answer (score 8):

In my case, there was a conflicting package installed under a different name, probably from a Visual Studio debug session.

To find all packages, I ran

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers > out.txt
```

I found the conflicting package there by the publisher name. Then I removed it:

```
Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers 5211b96d-a951-4e83-87f9-ef1af6cf7c97_2.0.11.0_x64__mgqd55e5kfvyj
```

After that, I could launch the app from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 7):

In Windows 10 I toggled from "Developer mode" to "Sideload apps" and back to "Developer mode" and it started working again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, which turned out to be due to separate installations of my app on the same computer but under different accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I re-installed my app from the Microsoft Store, then in Settings Add/Remove Programs I clicked on the '...' menu option to uninstall it.

Afterwards I was able to re-deploy the debug build okay.

I suspect there was some lock between the officially installed Microsoft Store version and the developer built version.

Answer (score 0):

I had this mistake after I tried to package my UWP app. I solved the issue by

1. Unloading my project
2. removing the appxbundle related tags from the project file
3. and just to be sure I afterwards clicked on the app project and click "add existing file", then I selected my manifest file

Answer (score 0):

I did the toggle between developer mode to sideload apps and back again as described by Matt - (search for Developer Features in Windows 10 to do that) - but then I got a new error "...unexpected host id encountered...".

I then changed the Solution Platform to x64 and my app started.

Answer (score 0):

I had package for upload to Store and fixed that bug in following way:

1. Rename .appxupload to .zip and extract files
2. Double-click .appxbundle
3. When app will be installed, remove it

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the 0x80074CF6 error code toghether with the DEP0700 error can be a very misleading one as it can refer to a lot of things.  I'll add what my problem for a simple, empty UWP project was (for which I did some slight modifications in the app manifest file for changing name, tiles, logo, etc.), maybe it helps someone else.

Turns out that for me, the error was actually due to failing to correctly locate and load up the splash screen image. To make things even weirder, I *restarted the computer and started up VS2017 as Admin* and got the full error message as:

> "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF6]
>   AppxManifest.xml(66,27): error 0x80070002: Cannot install or update
>   package Microsoft.SkypeUwpStub_daxd5377s5hcj because the splash screen
>   image [SplashScreen.png] cannot be located. Verify that the package
>   contains an image that can be used as a splash screen for the
>   application, and that the package manifest points to the correct
>   location in the package where this splash screen image can be
>   found.    SkypeUwpStub             "

Fixing it was pretty straightforward. I forgot to properly reference the Assets images from the actual folder on the disk (where I physically copied some asset files).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the property of the Package.appxmanifest file: Copy to exit directory = Always Copy

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem this way.

I had opened my project via a substituted drive, G:, which was mapped to a subdirectory of my C: drive. I closed the project and re-opened it using the full path via C:. Then everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

check the 'package name' and 'package family name'  in your Package.appxmanifest, no special characteres use only letters and '-'

Answer (score 0):

For .Net Maui .Net 7:

In my case, it was some wayward text in the project file that gave problems to the DotNet Maui project:

```
<ApplicationTitle>ContainersCR-LFGive feedbackCR-LFSearchCR-LFOnly running</ApplicationTitle>
```

On one hand, the CR/LF new line was the problem.
On the other, this garbage was there long before it started to fail.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run Visual Studio as admin,
2. Tools > NuGet Package Manager
3. `Get-AppxPackage -all *YourAppName* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers`

The app will be removed from all users. Now you can deploy an app.